# Why does non-contact voltage tester chirp when it touches my skin?

Tags: voltage, testing

I am getting a voltage tester (70v-1000 vac) go off (chirps once) when it touches my arm. If I move it up and down my arm it will chirp every few inches. Is this normal? And no, I'm not sitting in an electric chair at the state pen. LOL

This is the voltage tester. [https://www.amazon.com/ALLOSUN-GK7-Non-Contact-Voltage-70-1000V/dp/B07N4D9KCL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N4D9KCL)

Comment: I suspect there is a real explanation based on capacitance or something. But be warned! The linked item is a typical unlisted item. It looks and functions *similar* to a listed item (e.g., Klein, Fluke) but may or may not be as **safe**. That is a real concern in a situation where (a) False Negatives would be a big hazard and (b) there could be issues of current flowing *through* a tester. I would hope that isn't a problem here, as this is not the old-style "screwdriver tester" but be careful.

Comment: yes it's normal, and yes you have voltage potentials in your body, a sack of water absorbing emi/rfi/induced currents. A more expensive piece of equipment might filter out such background noise better. If you're in USA, use the finger test to confirm; a quick smack with one finger made by moving the whole arm in a chop. Or you can use a real DMM...

Comment: Fyi, my Fluke does the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Myself and my wife were able to get triple and quadruple beeps running my voltage tester over my frontal lope on my head, and no beeps on any other part of my body. My wife had single and double beeps on her skin This by definition means there is a magnetic field of 70 volts pertruding beyond the skin or head. I TRIED this on my cat and was able to only get triple beeps when my cat was playing. While laying down I was not able to get any beeps. It must mean when your brain is stimulated it produces more electricity and thus a larger field.